# SMTP Script for Google Mail

Tags: php, wordpress, email, smtp, gmail

I have got the below script from this [link](http://www.andrehonsberg.com/article/php-command-line-smtp-email-sender-for-gmail-using-pear). My Website is running with Digital Ocean hosting and I am unable to send a mail. 
Can you please help me out to work. Also, How do I get to know 
the actual mail failure ?

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

if (PHP_SAPI !== 'cli') exit;
if (count($argv) < 4) {
  echo 'Usage: ' . basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '  <recipient1#recipient2#...> "<subject>" <"msg" or file>'."\n";
  exit;
}

require_once "Mail.php";

$from         = "xxx@gmail.com";
$aRecipients  = (strpos($argv[1], '#')) ? explode('#', $argv[1]) : array($argv[1]);
$to           = '';
foreach ($aRecipients as $recipient) $to .= "{$recipient},";
$to           = rtrim($to, ',');
$subject      = $argv[2];
$body         = '';
if (file_exists($argv[3])) {
  echo "[+] Delivering file {$argv[3]} to {$to}\n";
  $body = file_get_contents($argv[3]); 
} else {
  $length = strlen($argv[3]);
  echo "[+] Delivering text with length of {$length} to {$to}\n";
  $body = "{$argv[3]}";
}

$host     = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com'); 
$port     = 465; 
$username = "xxxx@gmail.com";
$password = "xxx";

$headers = array(
    'From'    => $from,
    'To'      => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject
);

$smtp =& Mail::factory('smtp',
    array(
    'host'      => $host,
    'port'      => $port,
    'debug'     => true, // set to true if u want to see what happens in the background
    'auth'      => true,
    'username'  => $username,
    'password'  => $password
    )
);

$smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
echo "[+] Mail sent :)\n";

?>
```

Comment: try to replace `smtp.gmail.com` by `ssl://smtp.gmail.com`

Comment: Try to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-the-gmail-smtp-server-from-a-php-page?rq=1

Comment: Thanks and not working.

Comment: Can you suggest me where do I see the log which shows that mail is moved out from my box ?

Comment: check with if condition `if($smtp->send($to, $headers, $body)){
echo "working";
}else{
echo "failed"
|}`

it will not solve the issue but help to identify.

Comment: and set `'log' => true` for fetching more information

Answer (score 0):

change your host `smtp.gmail.com` to `ssl://smtp.gmail.com`

try this

```
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => '465',
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => 'XXX@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'xxx'
    ));
```

it might help you

Comment: Do you want me to hard code ?  Did I make anything wrong here ?

Comment: I want to say change `smtp.gmail.com` to `ssl://smtp.gmail.com`

Comment: I did and not see the outcome .